# Running eleventy build (via npm run) as AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, eleventy

I have a [eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/) Node project, which renders HTML from a JSON file.

Currently, I run this locally using `npm run` (which runs [the eleventy CLI](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/usage/))

Here's the workflow I have in my head:

- put the JSON file in a S3 bucket
- on each file change, run the HTML build
- push the output to a different S3 bucket, which serves the web page

Conceptually, I feel like this would be a standard FaaS use case.

Practically, I stumble over the fact that the Node.js-Lambda runtime always expects an explicit function handler to be invoked. It seems Eleventy does not provide a standard way to be invoked *from code* (or I have not discovered this yet).

I found that I *could* build my package into a Docker container and run the `npm run` as Entrypoint. This would surely work, but seems unnecessary, since the Lambda-provided Node.js runtimes *should* be capable of running my npm build command if I put my packages in the deployment artifact.

Do I have a knot in my brain? Anything I'm overlooking?
Would be happy about any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is supported as I don't see it documented, but I looked at the unit tests for Eleventy and saw many examples of this (https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/tree/master/test). I tried the following and it worked. Note that init an write are both async and I do NOT properly await them, I was just trying to get a simple example:

```js
const Eleventy = require('@11ty/eleventy');

const elev = new Eleventy('./input', './output');

elev.init();
elev.write();

console.log('done');
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! Thanks a lot for the hint and for taking the time having a look at this, Raymond! :)

Comment: FYI, please see the new documentation - it is MUCH better and clearer: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/programmatic/